# How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_0^\pi x^3cos(nx)dx)^2$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

For each $n \geq 1$, denote $C_n= \int_0^\pi x^3cos(nx)dx$.
Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {C_n}^2$

My suggestion:
The given sequence is proportional to Fourier coefficients of $x^3$ expansion to an even function in $[-\pi,\pi]$.
The sum that I get is: $\frac{9\pi^8}{224}$.

Am I in the right direction, how do I validate my answer?

Thanks

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BIntegrate%5Bx%5E3+Cos%5Bn+x%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D%5D%5E2%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D) validates your result.

Comment: Just compute every $C_n$ directly and then the series is a sum involving $\zeta\left(2\right)$, $\zeta\left(4\right)$, $\zeta\left(6\right)$ and $\zeta\left(8\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows easily from Parseval formula: assume $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n\cos nx, x \in [-\pi,\pi]$ is the Fourier series of the even extension of $x^3$ to $[-\pi, \pi]$.

Since for $n \ge1, a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx dx$ it follows that $a_n=\frac{2C_n}{\pi}$ while $a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\frac{\pi^3}{4}$

But Parseval says (easily seen by squaring, integrating and using orthogonality) that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2(x)dx=2\pi a_0^2+\pi\sum_{n \ge 1}a_n^2$$

Hence $$\frac{2\pi^7}{7}=\frac{\pi^7}{8}+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n \ge 1}C_n^2$$ from which the claimed result $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {C_n}^2=\frac{9\pi^8}{224}$ follows.